# AngularJS 1.2.9 ngRoute "unknown provider $routeProvider error with requireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-routing

I'm using angularJS-1.2.9 and angular-route-1.2.9 to set up routes for my application , i'm using requireJS as the dependency loader and modularize the code . I have added the ngRoute dependency into the AngularJS config , but still getting this following error in the chrome console **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvoider**

Here is my code

**main.js**

```
 require.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    paths: {
        angular: 'libs/angular-1.2.9',
        angularRoute: 'libs/angular-route-1.2.9'
    },
    shim: {
        'angularRoute': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularRoute'
        },
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});

require(['angular', 'angularRoute'], function (angular, angularRoute) {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });

    app.controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log('inside index');
    });
    app.config(
        function ($routeProvoider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'index_content.html',
                controller: 'indexController'
            })
        });
});
```

Here are my html files

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

index_content.html

```
<p>inside Index content</p>
<h1>testing the ang routes
```

Whats the issue here ?? Why is it still giving away the above mentioned error ?? How to fix this ??

Comment: Its a typo error. You have given "routeProvoider", change it to "routeProvider"

Comment: damn!!Yes,very stupid mistake !! Thank you @BKM ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo error on $routeProvider in the code I have rectified and placed the code below:

Code Snippet:

```
require(['angular', 'angularRoute'], function (angular, angularRoute) {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});

app.controller('indexController', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log('inside index');
});
app.config(
    function ($routeProvider) { //One typo here
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'index_content.html',
            controller: 'indexController'
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.config(
  function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/ResourceItem/:RE_RestoId',{
      templateUrl:'./partials/state-view.html',
      controller: function ($routeParams, ResourceService) {
        this.params = $routeParams;

        var that =  this;
        ResourceService.getResourceItem(this.params.RE_RestoId || "").success(function (data) {
          that.items = data;
        })

        this.addItemTo = function (resource)
        {
          if(!resource.items)
          {
            resource.items = [];
          }
          resource.items.push({TA_Code: this.newResourceItem });
          this.newResourceItem="";
        };

      },
      controllerAs:'ResourceItemCtrl'


    });
});
```

Comment: Can the error be generated when the URL path is not correct ?